# What is an EQÜAL WORD (patent pending)

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

An EQÜAL WORD (patent pending) is a special type of word. You'll know it when you see it.

Here are some examples, sponsored by the original, @JLee! It’s based off of the "What is a ___ Word" series, but you could look at this puzzle alone.
What is an EQUAL WORD, and why is it called that?

| EqÜal Words™ | Not EqÜal Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| equal | unequal |
| fauna | flora |
| anime | fun |
| briny | desaturates |
| serious | unfunny |
| print | point |
| drink | eat |
| git | better |

HINT PLAYLIST:

> The World Revolving, Toby Fox, Deltarune
>  Soundtrack Chapter 2.
>  Cover Up, Imagine Dragons, Night Visions

HINT THINGS:

> “Cover Up” means there is a single typo… but it can’t be removed for fear of the nomenclature crashing down…

Comment: Is the u umlaut significant,  or can you say?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being so late :(